# MSO color coding - accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, meta, design

The difference between the number of answers and a question with an accepted answer should be clearer on MSO.

[image: MSO] [image: Cooking.SE]

MSO vs Cooking.SE

**Edit** This could be an issue for Daltonics. In my case, I have the brightness of the monitor down to reduce fatigue and the yellow doesn't come out so bright. There are a number of ways to address this. 1. Remove the square from the non-accepted answers 2. Make the square of the accepted answers another form (a star!) 3. Make the square of the accepted answer greener (and remove the yellow letters for contrast). 4. etc.

**Edit** The real issue (if there is one) is that the difference is one-dimensional, while it should be multi-dimensional. [But don't take my word for it](http://webstandards.psu.edu/accessibility/tech/color/coding).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human%E2%80%93computer_interaction)

> 2. Avoid absolute judgment limits. Do not ask the user to determine the level of a variable on the basis of a single sensory variable (e.g. color, size, loudness). These sensory variables can contain many possible levels.

Comment: Hmm, I keep the brightness on my monitor(s) *extremely* low and I can still distinguish the yellow quite easily. I've never really paid that much attention to it, though. If I see an interesting question, I'll click through to read it regardless of whether it has an accepted answer. I either learn something by reading the accepted answer, or post a better answer of my own. Maybe it'll be accepted, maybe it won't. But this isn't a feature I use very heavily. It sounds more like a selective color blindness issue than a brightness problem, though.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Obligatory reference to [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/stylish) and [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) for custom workarounds.

Comment: Also see [this discussion](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10737/traffic-light-like-indicator-for-color-blind-users/10741#10741).

Comment: I've also found this VERY annoying. Stack overflow and MSO have by fark the hardest to differentiate answered/accepted answer indicators of _all_ SE sites. IHMO, they're also the least visually appealing. Using just the color is a nono, but in addition it's pretty hard to tell the difference when it's only font color _within a dark background_. It's a very slight change even for non-colorblind users.

Comment: @Straitjacket, I try use programs strait out of the box as that's the way any ordinary user will see the program. Only sometimes do I personalize a program ([if that's possible](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/tabbed-browsing-why-close-the-application-on-closing-the-last-tab)).

Comment: @SirTapTap, saying 'thanks' is considered to be 'noise', so I won't ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your second edit:

> The real issue (if there is one) is that the difference is
>   one-dimensional, while it should be multi-dimensional.

The colour of the answers box is not the only variable that changes, there is also a title added which states that `one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer`, where as questions without an accepted answer do not have any title at all.

```
<div title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer" class="status answered-accepted">
    <div class="mini-counts">N</div>
    <div>answers</div>
</div>
```

Having said that, there is an accessibility case for the text colour not contrasting enough with the background colour on the accepted answers: [WCAG 2.0 colour contrast](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#qr-visual-audio-contrast-contrast).

**In response to your [latest edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/100355/7):**

The running theme across all Stack Exchange sites is:

- No answers: One colour or no highlighting.
- 1+ answers: Different to no answers, usually in colour.
- Accepted answer: Different to both the above, usually with a new background.

My point is that these three things are different. An example:

In order from the left: [Home improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/), [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/), [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), [Role-playing games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)

[image: Examples of no answer, 1+ answer and accepted answer styles on Stack Exchange sites]

I think the three methods of highlighting should be kept because I believe it's important to be able to differentiate between no answers when looking to be the first to answer a question and some answers when looking to add information to a topic.

Also, it's nice to know which questions have accepted answers, so you can avoid spending too much time on them.

Comment: I don't usually look at the source code of websites :)

Comment: That makes sense, but the message appears if you hover over the answer numbers, as it is a title :P  In addition, titles are read by screen readers.

Comment: I already saw that and changed the text back. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think that the difference is visible enough, it's the same as it is on main (stackoverflow.com) and most users in the meta probably come from there anyway.. so they are used to `answered question = yellow text`